# Kali Linux change Windows boot logo

Tags: windows, boot, kali-linux

Before I installed Kali on my laptop, Windows would boot up with this logo, which I liked:

[image: Custom Logo]

After installing kali, I see that Windows now boots using a very low resolution of Windows 8/10 logo:

[image: Low res Windows logo]

Interestingly, when I boot Windows outside Kali by choosing "OS Boot Manager (UEFI) - Windows Boot Manager" (I select "System Setup", then I press F9 for Boot Manager) the custom logo is back.

I tried changing the chainloader path from the grub.cfg (the line that points at the Windows Boot file) but it didn't make a difference. So far in Google I've found ways to change the Grub background, not the Windows logo.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

After toying around, I found the answer.

It turns out that it all comes down to screen resolution. When Grubs loads, it brings up the boot options on a 640x480 resolution, thus forcing the low-res logo to pop up.

I uncommented the last line of this command in the /etc/default/grub file and changed it to the resolution supported by my computer:

```
#The resolution used on graphical terminal
#note that you can use only modes which your graphical card supports via VBE
#you can see them in real GRUB with the command 'vbeinfo'
GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080
```

and the original boot logo was back. I hope this information is useful to others.